# How to generate a new CSV file every time I run the experiment?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=Solution.get_row_header())
    df.to_csv('./data/cost_results.csv', index=False)
```

Every time I run the experiment, I get different results. However, the file "cost_results.csv" have exactly the same values every time I save it.

- I deleted the file every time to produce a new one, but the same problem occurred.
- I created a new .csv file with a different name to save the newly generated data, but the same data are there.

Is there anything I need to do or take care of before running the experiment?
What do you think is the problem?

Comment: You would have to post more of the code in order for anyone here to help you. If you are getting the same file written out on different runs of the program (even under different file names) then the data you are supplying the dataframe is the same. If you post how you are generating your `rows` variable, we might be able to help more. But I would start out by printing `rows` before loading it into the dataframe. You will most likely see that the data you are passing in is identical between the runs.

Comment: if `rows` is the same, the saved file will be the same, so did you verify `rows` actually changes>?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right file?  Is the timestamp on the csv file updated each time you run?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `print(df.head()` line before `df.to_csv('./data/cost_results.csv', index=False)` to make sure that df is actually changing each time. If `df` *is* changing, try to make sure that you are looking at the correct file (it's possible you're opening a file created earlier saved in a different location).

Aside from the indentation issue in the code snippet you shared, there shouldn't be any reason why this would not produce a different csv file if `rows` is actually changing.